# Compilation error on new Xamarin Forms project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I have installed Visual Studio for Mac (7.0.1 build 24 Community Edition), generated a new project using Forms, and could not get it to compile. The error shown makes no sense to me since the code looks correct.

I have not made *any* change to the code. It is as generated by the Wizard.

I have tried the following ways of setting up, on different machines:

1. Using Home Brew
2. Using the Visual Studio For Mac installer

Any pointers on how to work around this one will help.

Please look below Error Message

[image]

Comment: Could you show the complete file where this error is appearing? You named your app TestApp-Xamarin? The name of your app becomes the global namespace and C# doesn't allow dashes "-" in any identifier. Try creating a new app without the dash.

Comment: Hah !! The IDE should not have allowed this, or the error message should have been a little more explicit about it. Obviously led me down a different track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a dash in your namespace. Try using `TestAppXamarin` or `TestApp.Xamarin` instead:

```
namespace TestApp.Xamarin {
    public class TestAppClass { }
}
```